# LUKS encrypted drive not booting after modifying partition table with TestDIsk

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, encryption, luks

I screwed up my partition table the other day but had recovered it with TestDisk. After re-writing the partition table, I'm able to boot up into GRUB and subsequently the interface for entering my password to decrypt the encrypted partition.

However, after entering in the password, I get an error:

**Requested offset is beyond real size of device /dev/disk/by-uuid/..."UUID string here".**

Before entering in my password, the following errors are reported:

**lvmetad is not active yet, using direct activation during sysinit Volume group "ubuntu-vg" not found Cannot process volume group ubuntu-vg**

Does anyone point me in the right direction to fix this/explain to me what's causing this issue from a high level perspective? Thanks.